# How to control 200 relays with micro controller?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, fpga

I want to control 200 relays, I want to use AVR controller. Because I am out of pins,
I was thinking of connecting the micro controller (for routines and such things) to a FPGA and use the output of the FPGA for controlling the relay.

Is that a good idea or is there any other option which is simpler and more efficient to implement?

Comment: More information would be useful. 1) Do many relays change state at the same time or is only one relay being changed at any one time? 2) How fast do the relays need to be updated?

Comment: There are several inexpensive options but there are trade-offs with each. Knowing what is important to you would help us point you in a good direction.

Comment: IMO, it depends on how fast you want to be able to control those relays. Thee easiest way is to use some sorts or serial controllers, I2C or SPI are the most common and the easiest ones, but for 200, you need 25 controllers of 8 relays each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use some sort of addressing system, or demultiplexer. There are demultiplexer chips you can use. For example, if you used enough demultiplexers to give you 256 outputs from 8 address lines, that would allow you to use up to 256 relays, assuming the relays draw low enough power to be driven from it. And you'll want a way of latching the data.

If you have enough pins, here is how I would do it:

Your circuit will have 5 address lines, 8 data lines, and a clock line, which will allow your microprocessor to control up to 256 relays.

For your microprocessor to control the relays, it would output a byte to the circuit like so:

1. Put a byte, (8 bits) on the data lines of your circuit
2. Set the address lines, determining which batch of 8 relays you want the data to go to.
3. Take the clock line high, and then low.

If you want to control 256 relays, with a data bus of 8 bits, you will need 5 address lines. Between all five address lines, the different combinations will be able to select one of 32 locations, where each "location" represents 8 of your relays, their data settable by the 8 data lines. 8 x 32 = 256.

**For the decoders**, you could use the 54154 or similar. Each of those have 4 inputs and 16 outputs. You would need two of them. Or you could use something like 7411138, which has 3 inputs and 8 outputs. [the pdf is here](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/74ac11138.pdf).  It gives an example of how to construct a 5-address to 32-output circuit with multiple chips - this is exactly what you would want.

Then you would need **32 pieces of 8 bit latches**, such as the 74374, and also **32 pieces of octal darlington drivers** which would handle the relay's coil current. However, there are some **octal latching driver ICs** which combine these two needs. (That is for 256 relays. For 200 you would need 25, not 32)

You would not be able to power the relays directly from an FPGA, as they would draw too much current, and would be damaged by the spike the relay coil produces when de-energising. So you would need to have 32 octal darlington drivers as well as the FPGA.

Comment: isn't it better to just use different cplds and one micro controller for timing and such a things and use some FET between the CPLDs and relays ?

Comment: Each to their own; you could use a CPLD, it's a matter of preference. And FETs between the CPLD and relays would work, but you'd need diodes reverse biased across the relay coils, as the reverse voltage spike would otherwise damage the FETs and possibly the CPLDs. The advantage of not using a CPLD is you can split up the circuit onto different boards, which may make power management easier. (200 relays will consume an awful lot of power and space, I presume you'll want to split it up).

Answer (score 4):

CPLD devices are cheap per pin, but you may be better off to use some more modular approach, such as 8-bit addressable latches (74HC259) or 8-bit shift registers (74HC595) or power shift registers (TI TPIC series).

Whatever method you use, you will have to take care with layout, in particular as to the grounding, as you will be dealing with significant currents from the coils and perhaps significant EMI from the contacts. If you have many boards, it might be worth considering opto-isolation of data lines on a per-board basis.

Comment: If such a long chain (clock skew!) and galvanic connection of the grounds is feasible (depends on the number of relays that switch 'at once') the TPIC would be my choice. Otherwise IO extenders like MCP23017 + optocoupler/driver for each relay might be a better choice.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Yes, 200 relays switching at once sounds like a recipe for disaster. 8 might be okay, especially with isolation. If the TPICs or other SRs are used, there's no reason (other than saving pins) to use just one chain- 25 or 13 would be better.

Comment: using CPLD are really handy because if i have any done ant thing rung i just need to reprogram , do u think is it better to use CPLDs or spend more time before beginning the project to design a complicated combinational circuits ?

Comment: The circuits are very simple, not much logically can go wrong that fixing the driving firmware won't remediate. Modularity is nice if the spec could change .. Is adding 10 relays expensive or cheap? The biggest worry that has a real likelihood of coming true is committing to pcb(s) and finding an EMI issue like chattering or intermittent operation or resets. Using a number of CPLDs would work too.